# RMS value from wavelet coefficients

Tags: wavelet

I am confused on how to calculate the RMS value fo a signal from the wavelet coefficients. Here is a minimal python code for a sinusoidal sigmal of amplitude $1$ and $RMS=1/\sqrt{2}$

```
import numpy as np
import pywt
a = 1
fs = 16
f = 1
y = a*np.sin(2*np.pi* f * np.linspace(0, 1, fs))
rms = np.sqrt(np.mean(np.square(y)))
rms_theory = a/2**0.5
print(rms , rms_theory)

"""
0.6846531968814576 0.7071067811865475
"""

c = pywt.wavedec(y, 'db1')

"""
wavelet coefficients 'c'

+0.0000  
+2.3786  
-0.1963  -0.1963  
-0.6437  +0.5324  +0.5324  -0.6437  
-0.2876  -0.1470  +0.0909  +0.2686  +0.2686  +0.0909  -0.1470  -0.2876  
"""
```

How do I calculate the RMS from the knowledge of the wavelet coefficients alone?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I can't answer the second half of the question, but the reason your `rms` and `rms_theory` values are different is because you're not using linspace as you should. You're evaluating the sine over [0.0, 0.0625, ..., 0.9375, 1.0] instead of [0.0, 0.0625, ..., 0.9375] (last point not included). I haven't tested this, but `np.linspace(0, 1, fs, endpoint=False)` should fix this.

```
y = [sin(2*pi*(i/16)) for i in range(16)] # 0 through 15
(sum(n**2 for n in y)/len(y))**0.5 # 0.7071067811865476

y = [sin(2*pi*(i/16)) for i in range(17)] # 0 through 16
(sum(n**2 for n in y)/len(y))**0.5 # 0.6859943405700354
```